# Why in this program print None in output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation

Why in this program print **(None)** at the end of output?

```
def skip_elements(elements):

    for index, item in enumerate(elements):
        if index % 2 != 1:
            print(item, end=(" "))
    

print(skip_elements(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]))
print(skip_elements(['Orange', 'Pineapple', 'Strawberry', 'Kiwi', 'Peach']))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `print` when you're calling your fuction since you're already printing the result inside it.

Code:

```
def skip_elements(elements):

    for index in range(len(elements)):
        if index % 2 != 1:
            print(elements[index],end=" ")
            
skip_elements(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f","g"])
skip_elements(['Orange', 'Pineapple', 'Strawberry', 'Kiwi', 'Peach'])
```

Output:

```
a c e g Orange Strawberry Peach
```